# cocos2dx - ActionTween not working

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, chipmunk

In my game, I need to **rotate coin** for that I am using `ActionTween` like below

```
auto animateTo=ActionTween::create(.4, "roll", 0.f, M_PI_2);
auto animateFrom=ActionTween::create(.4, "roll", M_PI_2, M_PI);
auto seq=Sequence::create(animateTo,animateFrom, NULL);
coin->runAction(seq);
```

I have implemented the `ActionTweenDelegate` too like

```
class GameScene : Base, public ActionTweenDelegate
```

and implemented the method

```
void updateTweenAction(float value, const std::string& key);
```

But everytime I get

> **Assert failed: target must implement ActionTweenDelegate Assertion**
>   **failed: (dynamic_cast(target)), function**
>   **startWithTarget**

I have tried to set `startTarget` as well like

```
animateTo->setOriginalTarget(this);
animateFrom->setOriginalTarget(this);
```

But no luck, nothing working it crashes everytime.

Please if anyone experienced the same thing, help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

do this :

Inherit the **ActionTweenDelegate** (ActionTween's Protocol) to the class of the sprite on which you want to perform the ActionTween.

Also write

```
void updateTweenAction(float value, const std::string& key);
```

method in your class's `.h` & `.cpp` file.

Once the ActionTween runs update the sprite's key property with value;

Example :

```
MySprite *sprite = MySprite::create();
sprite->runAction(ActionTween::create(1.0, "scaleX", 1.0, 0.0))
```

and in MySprite.cpp

```
void updateTweenAction(float value, const std::string& key) {
    this->setScaleX(value);
}
```

make sure that key "scaleX" in tween constructor and in callback must be same.